# Set output framerate of a v4l2 device

Tags: v4l

I am using `v4l2loopback` v0.12.5 and `wf-recorder` to record my screen on wayland. I am looking to reduce the framerate of the video stream as read by my browser. Currently I am unable to get anything other than 60fps.

I have used version wf-recorder `0.2.1` and [this fork](https://github.com/ammen99/wf-recorder/pull/102) as it adds the option to set the framerate. However, I get the same output.

If I start `wf-recorder` with this command:

```
wf-recorder \
        -x yuv420p \
        -g "$x,$y ${width}x$height" \
        --muxer=v4l2 \
        --codec=rawvideo \
        --file="$device"
```

`/sys/devices/virtual/video4linux/video0/format` looks like this:

```
YU12:2560x1440@30
```

However the command output reports that the framerate is 60 not @30:

```
selected region 0 0 2560 1440
Framerate: 60
Choosing pixel format yuv420p
Output #0, video4linux2,v4l2, to '/dev/video0':
    Stream #0:0: Unknown: none (rawvideo)
```

If I open the device with `ffplay` I see that it reports 30fps:

```
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':B sq=    0B f=0/0
  Duration: N/A, start: 1102.869115, bitrate: 1327104 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 2560x1440, 1327104 kb/s, 30 fps
```

Using [webcamtests.com](https://webcamtests.com/) I get ~60fps reported.

If I instead start wf-recorder with the `-r` flag set to `6`:

```
wf-recorder \
        -x yuv420p \
        -r 6 \
        -g "$x,$y ${width}x$height" \
        --muxer=v4l2 \
        --codec=rawvideo \
        --file="$device"
```

`wf-recorder` reports `Framerate: 6` however `/sys/devices/virtual/video4linux/video0/format` still shows `YU12:2560x1440@30`.

This leads me to believe that the issue is not with `wf-recorder`, or rather that I can't set the framerate with that tool.

Instead I looked to change the settings on the device. Running:

```
echo "@6"| sudo tee /sys/devices/virtual/video4linux/video0/format
```

I see the format change to `YU12:2560x1440@6`. However, I see no change in the perceived framerate.

If I run:

```
sudo v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 -p 6
```

I see the format change to: `YU12:2560x1440@6000/1000` but again I see no change in the perceived framerate (still 60fps in my browser).

There don't seem to be any options to set for this on the `v4l2loopback` kernel module.

I'm running out of ideas - anything else to try or is my poor computer doomed to processes 100Mbit video streams forever? :D

Answer (score 1):

In the end I was able to do this with another v4l device and this gstreamer command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videorate drop-only=true ! video/x-raw,framerate=6/1 ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1
```

Comment: Did you see a performance improvement with this approach, or less resource usage?

Comment: I can’t remember I’m afraid. Shortly after I read about pipewire and how to enable that which solved my screen sharing issues in google meet. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PipeWire

Comment: The `videorate` control doesn't change anything in the source.  It simply drops/duplicates incoming frames to match the requested rate.  This will give you the output you require, but it doesn't reconfigure your camera.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to limit the frames per second to 10 by setting it on the v4l2loopback device like this before launching `wf-recorder`.

```
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video6 --set-parm 10
```

Playing the stream with `ffplay /dev/video6` after doing this confirmed the setting:

```
Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 2560x1410, 433152 kb/s, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
```

The help output of `v4l2-ctl` has the following about this setting:

```
$ v4l2-ctl --help-all
...
  -P, --get-parm     display video parameters [VIDIOC_G_PARM]
  -p, --set-parm <fps>
                     set video framerate in <fps> [VIDIOC_S_PARM]
...
```